# I feel as if I'm having duplications of code in my Nginx default file

Tags: nginx

This is my `sites-available/default` Nginx file. As you can see it contains my default settings, and my site's settings.

```
server {
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    # 443 ssl http2;
    # [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name contfix.co.il www.contfix.co.il;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl/contfix.co.il.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl/contfix.co.il.key;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl/dhparam.pem;

    root /var/www/html/contfix.co.il;

    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|ttf|woff)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }

    location ~*  \.(pdf)$ {
        expires 30d;
    }
}
```

I feel as though I have some code duplications there that make my **site-specific** server block too long for no good reason, hence unloyal to the DRY standard.

I tried to remove everything that seemed to me as a duplication of the default server block at the top, but each time it only broke the server.

Do I really have any duplication there? Is there anything I could move to the top default server block?

My purpose is to have site-specific server blocks short as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the purpose of the default `_` server block. It does not contain the `default` settings for all other server blocks, it is the block that is used when no other block matches a server request made by the client (or in other words, when no webapp or website is available). You still have to configure each server block independently.

You could work with includes, but while that makes single changes easier because you only have to change it once for all server blocks, it makes the overall config more confusing.

Comment: Will you say it's a best practice to delete `default` and work only with `nginx.conf`?

Comment: Is there anything I could "pass" on, in my server blocks? Without includes of course?

Comment: No idea, I only use nginx for small installations and never had that problem. And there is no way I know of to reduce the duplication.